# Moving 3 different sizes of registers to the left

Tags: assembly, atmega

Is there an easy universal way to move 3 registers as

- 0000 0001
- 0000 0011
- 0000 0111

that will be changed to

- 1000 0000
- 1100 0000
- 1110 0000

I want it to be universal not separate subroutines for each one of them.

My architecture is: `ATmega8535 - 16 bits`.

What I thought of doing is:

```
changeOrientation:  swap r0 //move right nibble to the right e.g. from 0000 0001 to 0001 0000
                    com r0  //change all 0 to 1 and 1 to 0 so e.g. from 0001 0000 to 1110 0000
                    andi r0, F0 //keep only left nibble so e.g. from 1111 1110 to 1111 0000
```

and I got stuck. I can't think of anything right now I would appreciate some help and input. Thanks!

Comment: do you want to reverse or rotate until you have a bit in the low order bit? Question isn't clear what it would do in all cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if it is really just those 3 cases:

```
loop1: ror r0
       brcs loop1
```

That will rotate right until the carry flag is 0, meaning the last 1 has been shifted in.